# Отношение @ManyToMany для однотипных сущностей

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm

Имеется область взаимосвязь между однотипными сущностями:

```
@JoinTable(name = "QMS_TARGET_TARGET_LINK",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_1_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_2_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false))
@ManyToMany
private Set<Target> relatedTargets;
```

При добавлении Target в relatedTargets, связь работает только для первой стороны, подскажите как правильно настроить связь в данной ситуации.

Comment: `связь работает только для первой стороны` это, что имеется ввиду? Вы хотите, чтоб когда вы делаете `target1.getRelatedTargets().add(target2)`, то выполнялось атоматически `target2.getRelatedTargets().contains(target1)`?

Comment: хочу чтобы связь @ManyToMany нормально работала, те когда  target1.getRelatedTargets().add(target2), то выполнялось автоматически target2.getRelatedTargets().add(target1),  сейчас добавление происходит только с одной стороны target1.getRelatedTargets().add(target2)

Answer (score 1):

Правильное решение это не полагаться на ORM или БД, а сделать это на уровне классов, т.е. чтоб это работало везде. Это часть бизнес
логики, и со всех сторон лучше, если это будет прямо выражено в коде. В частности, код будет автоматически поддерживать инварианты и, скажем, в unit-тестах:

```
class Target {
  private Set<Target> relatedTargets;

  public void associateWith(Target association) {
    relatedTargets.add(association);
    association.getRelatedTargets().add(this);
  }
}
```

И дальше ползуйтесь этим методом для установки связи.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую Ваш вариант.

Answer (score 0):

В классе `Target` используйте конструкцию:

```java
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "relatedTargets")
private List<ДРУГОЙ КЛАСС> smth;
```

Comment: Мне нужна связь Target с Set<Target> relatedTargets